# How to retrieve a data on the same row in a MS Access database using Visual C#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2013

Please I want to know how to retrieve a data on the same row in a  MS Access database using Visual C#

I want to get the meaning of a keyword from my database when it is selected from a combo box

Here is my code;

```
private void cmd_SearchResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{   

   connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
             Data Source=C:\Users\hp\Documents\KnowledgeBase.accdb;
             Persist Security Info=False;";

    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connection.ConnectionString))
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {                
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandText = "select Meaning from KnowledgeBase where Keyword = @Keyword";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Keyword", String.Copy(cbo_SearchResult.Text));
        connection.Open();
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            lbl_Display.Text = reader["Meaning"].ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like you get the `[Meaning]` of a `[Keyword]` with that code. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Uhm, what is the variable _connection_? Where do you initialize it?

Comment: You are not opening the connection that is assigned to the command. It was the command's connection but then you change it. So you are getting an exception which is typically something you would include in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like the following.  I'm not sure what the "connection" object is but lets go with a simple string as shown.

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
         Data Source=C:\Users\hp\Documents\KnowledgeBase.accdb;
         Persist Security Info=False;";

using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {                
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "select Meaning from KnowledgeBase where Keyword = @Keyword";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Keyword", cbo_SearchResult.Text);

        object result = command.ExecuteScalar();

        if (result != null)
        {
            lbl_Display.Text = result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to correct OP's code you might want to point out that it is pointless to set the text of a label in a loop, that ExecuteScalar should be considered, that AddWithValue is discouraged and String.Copy is unnecessary.

Comment: Further cleaned up code based on suggestions from @Crowcoder.